# Append elemnets to numpy nd array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

After performing [houghlinesp](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)

I trying to filter out the line that has an angle of 85 to 90 degress

```
def filter_line(lines):
"""
Filter the input the input lines to +/- 5 deg.
    Parameters:
        image: The output of a Canny transform.
"""
filtered_line= np.empty([0, 1, 4])
if lines is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        l = lines[i][0]
        dx = l[2]-l[0]
        dy = l[3]-l[1]
        angle= degrees(atan2(dy, dx))
        if (angle > 85):
            print(l)
            print(type(l))
            print(l.shape) 
            np.reshape(l, (1, 1, 4))
            print(l.shape)
            filtered_line = np.append(filtered_line, l, axis=0)
    return filtered_line
```

type(lines)  --> 'numpy.ndarray'

lines.shape --> (29, 1, 4)

line --> [[[339 475 339   4]] [[224   4 416   4]] [[269  33 400  33]] ...]]]

l --> [339 475 339   4]

l --> 'numpy.ndarray'

l --> (4,)

I am looking to output the filtered_line of same dimension

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Not sure how to make it work.

Comment: `filtered_line` has shape `(0,1,4)`, so anything you append should have shape `(1,4)`, but your `l` has shape `(4,)`. Try `np.append(filtered_lines, lines[i])`.

Comment: when i did print(filtered_lines.shape) --> (4,) . But i am looking for the dimensions that look same as lines (x, 1, 4 ) . Initially its (29, 1, 4) which mean 29 lines and after filtering it could be some x (x < 29).

Comment: `np.reshape(l, (1, 1, 4))` doesn't happen in place, you need to assign it. So try `l = np.reshape(l, (1, 1, 4))`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is any benefit in using np.append repeatedly instead of list comprehension followed by conversion to array. I would just do

```
def filter_line(lines):
    """
    Filter the input the input lines to +/- 5 deg.
        Parameters:
            image: The output of a Canny transform.
    """
    filtered_lines = []
    if lines is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        l = lines[i][0]
        dx = l[2]-l[0]
        dy = l[3]-l[1]
        angle= degrees(atan2(dy, dx))
        filtered_lines.append(l)
        if (angle > 85):
            filtered_lines.append(l)
    return np.array(filtered_lines)
```